# change version of servlet, how to change version with no errors

Tags: java, xml, servlets

When i create new servlet in NetBeans i have this code in `web.xml`

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
```

I have to use version 3.0, it was specified in my homework

I should use this code in `web.xml`

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

but If i will change native code then i cant compile servlet.

How can i fix that ?

Comment: does  your container implement servlet 3.0 spcecs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  change the below line

```
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
```

to point to schema for 3.0

Comment: yee, i tried change it but i had an error, now it works fine, thx

Comment: you can use the below configuration <web-app version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">